# corona sdk state saving using json to return variables

Tags: json, coronasdk, read-write, state-saving

Hi I am building an app using corona sdk which is an interactive ebook. What I need to be able to do is save current variables and then load an external file on startup containing the scene the user is on as well as the choices already made. I store all of these as global variables with each choice being given a value of either 0 or 1 and the scene name stored in an array with a designated number ie. scene 1 =  1 in the array. Any help would be unbelievably appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Create a table with the variables you want to store and use these two functions to save the table in a file and to read the file and return the stored table.

```
local function write(table, fileName)
    local filePath = system.pathForFile( fileName, system.DocumentsDirectory )
    local file = io.open( filePath, "w" )
    local encodedTable = json.encode(table)
    file:write(encodedTable)
    io.close( file )
end

local function read(fileName)
    local filePath = system.pathForFile( fileName, system.DocumentsDirectory )
    local file = io.open( filePath, "r" )

    if file then
        local contents = file:read("*all")
        local decodedTable = json.decode(contents)

        io.close( file )
        return decodedTable
    else
        return false
    end
end
```